# Update MySQL table using JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table by joining with two other tables, but I need to group by the ID of the updated table, something like :

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.AForeignID = T3.ID
FROM TableOne T1 
LEFT JOIN TableTwo T2 ON T2.ID = T1.BForeignID 
LEFT JOIN TableThree T3 ON T3.Code = T2.Code AND T3.ACode  = T1.ACode 
GROUP BY T1.ID
```

But I cant use GROUP BY , it shows an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use group by without an aggregation function  (min(), max(), count().

the GROUP BY clause  define the columns which are used to perform an aggregation

```
UPDATE T1
FROM TableOne T1 
LEFT JOIN TableTwo T2 ON T2.ID = T1.BForeignID 
LEFT JOIN TableThree T3 ON T3.Code = T2.Code AND T3.ACode  = T1.ACode 
SET T1.AForeignID = T3.ID
```

and the update with join  should use an UPDATE  .. FROM   .. JOIN syntax

..